# Sufficient and necessary condition for convexity

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Is it true that the sufficient and necessary condition for a real-valued function $f$ to be convex on an open interval $I$ is that i) $f$ is continuous on $I$ and ii) $\bar{D}_2 f \geq 0$, where
$$
\bar{D}_2 f(x) = \mathrm{lim~sup}_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^2}.
$$

Obviously this is a necessary condition, but it's very hard for me to get some clues about the sufficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I can answer my own question with the help of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584623/convexity-and-maxima).

Suppose $\bar{D}_2 f(x)\geq 0$ and let $g_n(x) = f(x) + x^2/n$, we have $\bar{D}_2 g_n = \bar{D}_2 f + 2/n > 0$. Since the limit of convex functions is still a convex function, we only need to show that each $g_n$ is convex. Suppose $g_n$ is not convex, we have that for some number $m$, $g_n(x) + mx$ has a local maximum at $z$ inside the open interval $(a,b)$. This means that, within some sufficiently small interval $(z-h,z+h)$, we have $2g(z) \geq g(z+\delta) + g(z-\delta), \forall\delta, 0\leq\delta < h$, which contradicts the fact that $\bar{D}_2 g_n > 0$. Hence $g_n$ is convex and $f$ is convex.